# As a beginner in java, should I be aiming to keep my code efficient?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in java(under a month of self -study) and as an aspiring developer I'd like to think that this topic is something I should be well versed in(excuse me for my lack of terminology here)

Here's  my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Type a word: ");
        String word = reader.nextLine();
        if (word.isEmpty()) {
            Collections.reverse(wordsList);
            System.out.println("You typed the following words: ");
            for (String wordss : wordsList) {
                System.out.println(wordss);
            }
            break;
        }
        wordsList.add(word);
    }
}
```

I apologize for bad indentation.

In this line:

```
for (String wordss: wordsList) 
    print(wordss)
```

I believe I am creating an entirely new string array named wordss, and it is containing all the identical info of wordsList after it was being updated. Would it be more efficient to write a loop that prints out each of the words in the wordsList array rather than allocating more space for another array?(please correct my ignorance where necessary) Is it a better practice to be more simple with my code?

My other question is that I have my loop running an if check after every time a new word is input. I also believe that this is inefficient - so would it be better to simply move the check to after the words are added?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between a normal for-loop and a for-each loop?

Comment: You're not "_creating an entirely new string array_"; not least because you have an `ArrayList` and not a `String[]`. You are _looping over_ a `List` you already have.

Comment: I guess but it doesn't have to be a for loop. It would update a counter variable each time and have it print the each index of the array(I hope that makes sense as I'm bad at explaining lol)

Comment: As far as inefficiencies go, calling `Collections.reverse(wordsList)` every time is wasteful - I would suggest using a `LinkedList` which implements the `Deque` interface and then calling the [`Deque.addFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#addFirst-E-) method.

Comment: Okay thanks! I wasn't sure what was going behind the scenes as I was just working with code I've seen in examples. I"ll look in to the oracle tutorial there too.

Comment: Imho, you should never use a loop with an index variable unless you have to. Generally, I would recommend for a beginner to aim for readabilty, not efficiency, especially in Java, as it is not the language to use when efficiency is really important.

Comment: @Kirinya "_Java, as it is not the language to use when efficiency is really important_" - evidence please.

Comment: IMO, readability > performance. Unless you work with really large datasets, it is more important that it's possible to understand the code, rather than it executing in 1 millisecond instead than 2. Make it readable first, then refactor if performance becomes an issue. When it comes to loops and in memory operations, modern computers are so fast that it's probably not going to be a bottleneck.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, rather an ArrayDeque.

Comment: You should focus your learning efforts on being able to nail down a good algorithm with low big-O complexity. The second objective is raising awareness of the most common performance pitfalls, like concatenating a string in a loop (which has hidden O(n2) complexity). A distant third-level goal are all the fine details of micro-performance, which begin to matter only when you have mastered the first two.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you wrote is correct. Just little modification has to be done to accept the words and termination. Below changed code works for termination if 'Enter' is press one more time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("Type a word: ");
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println("Type a word: ");
            String word = reader.nextLine();
            wordsList.add(word);
            if (word.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("You typed the following words: ");
                for (String typedWord : wordsList) {
                    System.out.println(typedWord);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you answered the question OP had